# Animating view after a specific period of time in Android

Tags: android, animation

I am working on an Android app that has tabs in a viewpager, due to the fact that the viewpager and toolbar take up a good amount of space my app does not look nice on small phones so I was thinking of automatically animating my toolbar off the screen to save screen space, after `3s` from the time the user opened the app or touched the screen the toolbar is to animate off the screen, the issues comes in when a user touches the screen multiple times, I tend to have the  program process all those animate ins and outs, since am using a `Handler` I tried using the `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) and removeCallbacks(hideToolBar)` methods which removes all runnables from the handler but it still processes all of them, my aim is that when a user touches the screen before multiple times before or after `3s` its not to hide the toolbar, but its tending to hide then reveal then hide and so on, below is my code.

Method that reveals the ToolBar if hidden

```
 private void showToolBar()
{
    if (toolbarHidden) {
        toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
        toolbarHidden = false;
    }
}

    private void hideToolBar()
{

    hideRevealHandler = new Handler();
    hideToolBar = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                if (!toolbarHidden) {
                    toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
                    toolbarHide = true;
                }

        }
    };
    hideRevealHandler.postDelayed(hideToolBar, 3000);

}
```

Then am overriding `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` to capture any even on the screen so that if toolbar was hidden its revealed.

```
   @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
     //Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
  if(!toolbarHideCommand) {
      toolbarHideCommand = true;
      try {
          hideRevealHandler.removeCallbacks(hideToolBar);
      } catch (NullPointerException w) {
          w.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
   else 
      toolbarHideCommand = false;


    showToolBar();
   hideToolBar();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
 //Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
 if(!toolbarHideCommand) {
  toolbarHideCommand = true;
  try {
      hideRevealHandler.removeCallbacks(hideToolBar);
  } catch (NullPointerException w) {
      w.printStackTrace();
  }

}
else 
  toolbarHideCommand = false;


  showToolBar();
  // change in code is here. Now it will process only new one.
  try {
     hideRevealHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
  } catch (Exception w) {
    w.printStackTrace();
  }
  hideToolBar();
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}
```